# How to achieve this nested flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: [![See the layout][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJABl.png]

I am having flex container with left and right flex basis of 50%.
Now I want to achieve the left flex to have two inputs in the first line and each input in seperate lines, how to come up with the layout?

Comment: Have you explored the many articles on CSS Flex? Do you have some code to share? Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have given the left and right as flex-basis:50% inside the container. Inside the left section I am having the form with the two inputs as a row, and the rest all input in a single row.
I tried giving the form as flex and changed to column direction.Whn I give the row as flex:1, due to the direction it is acting towards the height

Comment: Instead of Flexbox, how about [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) for _left_'s layout?

Comment: @OskarGrosser there is not much difference in flexbox and grid in this example. It is a very basic layout and task. Flexbox would have better compatibility while there is no gain in using a grid (neither by reducing the coding effort nor by adding efficiency or semantics to it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `flex-basis` here. The simply solution is to give the inputs a width of 100%. Then to address the first 2 inputs by using `:nth-child(-n +2)`. Give them a different width that is calculated by `(100% - gap-width) / 2` (will also work with `:nth-child(n + 3)`):

```css
:root {
  --gap: 1rem;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

input:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  width: calc((100% - var(--gap)) / 2);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input placeholder="firstname">
  <input placeholder="lastname">
  <input placeholder="email adress">
  <input placeholder="phone number">
</section>
```

@OskarGrosser mentioned that you can use CSS Grid for this too. While your question specifically asked for Flexbox, I do not believe that this is the better solution with compatibility and use/effort in mind.

In a grid layout you create a 2 column grid with `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`. Then you can let every input with the exception of the first 2 inputs span 2 columns by using `grid-column: span 2`. For that, you can combine the above mention `nth-child` selector with the `:not` selector.

```css
:root {
  --gap: 1rem;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: var(--gap);
}

input:not(:nth-child(-n + 2)) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input placeholder="firstname">
  <input placeholder="lastname">
  <input placeholder="email adress">
  <input placeholder="phone number">
</section>
```

Comment: +1 Great examples. Flexbox is definitely better in regards to compatibility, but CSS Grid easily allows for inline gaps without having to calculate widths and its code shows intent more clearly. In case you target browsers supporting both, I'd recommend to use CSS Grid for grid-like, and Flexbox for flow-like designs.